# Regex search for ONLY domains, ignoring domain component of URL

Tags: python, regex

Given a block of arbitrary text, I need a regex pattern that will find/extract domains only, ignoring scheme and subdomain components of domains, and ignoring strings entirely if there is a path (these are being extracted as URLs)

Example Text:

`www.google.com/example`
`www.stackoverflow.com`
`https://reddit.com`
`https://www.facebook.com/username`

Matches:
`reddit.com`
`stackoverflow.com`

I have tried the following

`\b((?=[a-z0-9-]{1,63}\.)(xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,63}\b`

Which of course will return:
`www.google.com`
`www.stackoverflow.com`
`reddit.com`
`www.facebook.com`

Comment: Just to confirm I've understood, you want `reddit.com` even though it's a URI, because there's no path component to the URI (`https://reddit.com`)?  Would `https://reddit.com/` also count as having no path?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That's a great question. For the purposes of this, I would expect `https://reddit.com/ ` to be ignored to minimize complexity.

Comment: This would work if you included the trailing slash... working on a version for when we don't want those (surprisingly that's harder)... `\b((?=[a-z0-9-]{1,63}\.)(xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,63}\/?[^\S]`

Comment: Try this: `\b((?=[a-z0-9-]{1,63}\.)(xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,63}\b(?:[^\/\.]|$)`

Comment: I don't know what happened to my other comment, but this worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
\b(?!www\.)(?:(?=[a-z0-9-]{1,63}\.)(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,63}\b(?![/.])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7sDL4C/1).

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!www\.)` -  no `www.` immediately on the right is allowed
- `(?:(?=[a-z0-9-]{1,63}\.)(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+` - one or more occurrences of

  - `(?=[a-z0-9-]{1,63}\.)` - a positive lookahead that requires 1 to 63 ASCII lowercase letters, digits or hyphens and then a `.` immediately to the right of the current location
  - `(?:xn--)?` - an optional `xn--` char sequence
  - `[a-z0-9]+` - one or more lowercase ASCII letters or digits
  - `(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*` - zero or more sequences of `-` and one or more lowercase ASCII letters or digits
  - `\.` - a `.` char
- `[a-z]{2,63}` - 2 to 63 lowercase ASCII letters
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?![/.])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a `/` or `.` immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Looks good; though one potential typo... should the final `(?![/.])` be `(?![/\.])` (i.e. to escape the dot so it doesn't match any char)?

Comment: @JohnLBevan Dots in character classes/bracket expressions are treated as regular chars, not special chars, `\.` = `[.]`

Comment: Ah thank-you / sorry for doubting you ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
text = '''www.google.com/example
www.stackoverflow.com
https://reddit.com
https://www.facebook.com/username
'''


re.findall(r'(?<=(?:www.|tps:))[/]*([a-z]+.com)(?![/])', text)

['stackoverflow.com', 'reddit.com']
```

Comment: This is definitely close! I'd want google.com skipped due to the path.

Comment: @vnoice, I have updated the answer. Please take a look.